./create backup from on prem script not working properly in oracle linux
[oracle@srv1 oci-cli-scripts]$ ./create_backup_from_onprem --config-file /home/oracle/.oci/config     --profile DEFAULT     --display-name testbackup     --compartment-id ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaajrsprf3hmjr7xixz22gft36vmfz232ydxliw455ndu7rgpxghq5a     --availability-domain PHX-AD-1     --edition ENTERPRISE_EDITION_HIGH_PERFORMANCE     --opc-installer-dir /home/oracle/oci/opc_installer/opc_installer     --tmp-dir /home/oracle/oci/onprem_upload
/home/oracle/oci/lib/oracle-cli/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/oci/_vendor/httpsig_cffi/sign.py:10: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography. The next release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.6.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend  # noqa: F401
Connecting to Oracle database
Oracle version is:19.0.0.0.0
Checking the archive log mode of the database
Checking if the database is open
Getting database name and database unique name
Database Id:2940187580 Name:ORADB UniqueName:oradb
Fetching character set
Character Set:AL32UTF8
Fetching national character set
National Character Set:AL16UTF16
Fetching rac mode
Rac mode:FALSE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create_backup_from_onprem", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(create_backup_from_onprem())
  File "/home/oracle/oci/lib/oracle-cli/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oracle/oci/lib/oracle-cli/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/oracle/oci/lib/oracle-cli/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/oracle/oci/lib/oracle-cli/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oracle/oci/lib/oracle-cli/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oracle/oci/lib/oracle-cli/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/oci_cli/scripts/database/dbaas.py", line 281, in create_backup_from_onprem
    client = cli_util.build_client('database', 'database', ctx)
  File "/home/oracle/oci/lib/oracle-cli/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/oci_cli/cli_util.py", line 578, in build_client
    if ctx.obj['connection_timeout']:
KeyError: 'connection_timeout'
[oracle@srv1 oci-cli-scripts]$

try upgrading OCI and still it didn't work , I wanted to take onprem backup and restore it to OCI environment.

In the build_client function of cli_util.py, locate and fix the relevant part like this:
if 'connection_timeout' not in ctx.obj:
ctx.obj['connection_timeout'] = 60  # Default to 60 seconds
if ctx.obj['connection_timeout']:
if 'read_timeout' in ctx.obj and ctx.obj['read_timeout']:
client.base_client.timeout = (ctx.obj['connection_timeout'], ctx.obj['read_timeout'])
else:
client.base_client.timeout = (ctx.obj['connection_timeout'], client.base_client.timeout[1])
else:
if 'read_timeout' in ctx.obj and ctx.obj['read_timeout']:
client.base_client.timeout = (client.base_client.timeout[0], ctx.obj['read_timeout'])
./create_backup_from_onprem --config-file /home/oracle/.oci/config --profile DEFAULT --display-name oradb --availability-domain $AD --edition ENTERPRISE_EDITION_HIGH_PERFORMANCE --opc-installer-dir /home/oracle/oci/opc_installer/opc_installer --tmp-dir /home/oracle/oci/onprem_upload --compartment-id

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
